# Don't want to run Setup test classes in parallel and rest File In parallel in TESTNG

Tags: java, automation, parallel-processing, testng, testng.xml

I was Trying To make a test Suite for My automation I have Create The testng.xml file .

In That file I have 2 sections 1 is Setup and the other is Execution.
Want to run Setup without parallel and After Setup completion Execution part Should run in parallel.

Sample Of TestNG.xml

```
    <suite name="sample" parallel="test" thread=3>
    //Setup Test Runs in the begin without parallel 
    <test name="Setup">
    
    <classes>
    <class name="A"/>
    <class name="B"/>
    </classes>
    
    </test>
    
    // Below tests to be ran in parallel.
    <test name "execution" ><classes><class name="X1"/><class name="X2"/><class name="X3"/>/classes></test>
    <test name "execution2" ><classes><class name="Y1"/><class name="Y1"/></classes></test>
 <test name "execution3"><classes><class name="Z1/><class name="Z1"/></classes></test>
    </suite>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `parallel` attribute on the `<suite>` tag will be applied for the hole file.

You have to split multiple parallel configurations on several files and use all in the next way:

1 Create `setup.xml` with `parallel="none"`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Run-Setup" parallel="none">
    <test name="Setup">
        <classes>
            <class name="A"/>
            <class name="B"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

2 Create `execution.xml` with `parallel="tests" thread-count="3"`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Run-Executions" parallel="tests" thread-count="3">
    <test name "execution" >
        <classes>
            <class name="X1"/>
            <class name="X2"/>
            <class name="X3"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name "execution2" >
        <classes>
            <class name="Y1"/>
            <class name="Y2"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name "execution3">
        <classes>
            <class name="Z1"/>
            <class name="Z2"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

3 Create `master-testng-suite.xml` which refers all of them:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Run-all-testNG-files">
    <suite-files>
        <suite-file path="setup.xml"/>
        <suite-file path="execution.xml"/>
    </suite-files>
</suite>
```

4 Run `master-testng-suite.xml`

---

**Reference**

https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parallel-running